# cursor.limit gives me an empty array result

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I use query and find..limit methods, every thing work fine but when I use `limit(req.query.limit)` and

`localhost:8000/api/hotels?featured=true&limit=2`

set limit on my api request it give me an empty array

here it is my code :

```js
export const getHotels = async (req, res, next) => {
const { min, max, ...others } = req.query;
  try {
    const hotels = await Hotel.find({
      ...others,
      cheapestPrice: { $gt: min | 1, $lt: max || 999 },
    }).limit(req.query.limit);
    res.status(200).json(hotels);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};
```

here it is the routes:

```js
router.get("/",getHotels)
```

when I removed `req.query.limit` and replace it with number it work fine and I get the limit

Comment: What's the data type of `req.query.limit`?

Comment: Data type is string

Comment: use `limit(parseInt(req.query.limit))`. `limit` need to be integer.

Comment: I try it and I still got an an empty array

Comment: Will you show how you convert `req.query.limit` to an integer?

Comment: const hotels = await Hotel.find({
      ...others,
      cheapestPrice: { $gt: min | 1, $lt: max || 999 },
    }).limit(parseInt(req.query.limit));
here it is

Comment: If you place `console.log(req.query.limit)` in the `try` block, what does it show?

Comment: I try it with typeof and still a string ..but I got a number as result I will try convert to int by Number()

Comment: limit(Number(parseInt(req.query.limit))) I do it like that and still I got string

Comment: its useless to Number and parseInt in the same time. use parseInt instead. and try to add limit within `const { min, max, limit,...others } = req.query;